# Replace background image by fading

Tags: image, vb.net-2010, effects

I have a *WinForm* in *VB.Net* with some images at the background which change every 5 seconds by a timer. The problem is that they change immediately and this does not look nice. I would like to add some fade-in effects, but I got the error that opacity is not a property for `tableLayout.backgroundimage`. I can only fade the form, but that's not what I want.

Here is my code:

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    If imageNum > 3 Then
        imageNum = 1
    End If
    Select Case imageNum
        Case 1
            Me.TableLayoutPanel4.BackgroundImage = Global.posta1.My.Resources.Resources.foto1
            For FadeIn = 0.0 To 1.1 Step 0.1
                Me.Opacity = FadeIn
                Threading.Thread.Sleep(100)
            Next
            rd_btn1.Checked = False
            rd_btn2.Checked = True
        Case 2
            Me.TableLayoutPanel4.BackgroundImage = Global.posta1.My.Resources.Resources.foto3
            rd_btn2.Checked = False
            rd_btn3.Checked = True
            For FadeIn = 0.0 To 1.1 Step 0.1
                Me.Opacity = FadeIn
                Threading.Thread.Sleep(100)
            Next
        Case 3
            Me.TableLayoutPanel4.BackgroundImage = Global.posta1.My.Resources.Resources.foto2
            For FadeIn = 0.0 To 1.1 Step 0.1
                Me.Opacity = FadeIn
                Threading.Thread.Sleep(100)
            Next
            rd_btn3.Checked = False
            rd_btn1.Checked = True
    End Select
    imageNum = imageNum + 1
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I do know it's not possible to set the opacity of a single control, maybe you can do it by drawing the control yourself but you have to research about that because I have no knowledge about drawing controls yourself..

Answer (score 0):

I'm a novice but what I would think would work would be to draw (using the `PaintEventArgs` argument of the paint event of the control) to do this:

- Draw both the old and the new pic.
- Lessen the alpha value of the old pic, whilst increasing the new pic's alha value, until they are `0.0`, and `1.0`

Hope this helped. Sorry if it didn't.

;)